# How to increment directory number in bash?

Tags: bash, increment

I have a watchdog implemented in bash that is restarting a service on certain conditions and it does move the old logs to an old directory.

The problem is that I do want to move the logs to `old_1`, `old_2`, ... if previous one exists.

How can I implement this in bash?

Comment: Why don't use a timestamp for the name of the directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can search for the first non-existing log like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=1
while [[ -f log_$num ]] ; do
    let num++
done
echo Fresh new: log_$num
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a pain to write, handle missing folders (which will break choroba solution for instace). This is why most systems requiring logs are just suffixing their names with dates, I encourage you to do the same, its easier to handle and also easier to retrieve a log afterward.